# Direct limit of complexes from cocycle property up to homotopy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, cohomology

Suppose that we have a directed set $(I, \leq)$, and a set of maps
\begin{equation}
f_{i,j} : C^*(A_i) \to C^*(A_j), \quad i \leq j,
\end{equation}
of singular cochain complexes of topological spaces $A_k$, such that $f_{i,i} = Id_{C^*(A_i)}$, and satisfying the following "homotopy cocycle" property
\begin{equation}
\text{for all } i \leq j \leq k, \quad f_{j,k} \circ f_{i,j} \text{ is homotopic to }  f_{i,k}.
\end{equation}
Can we define the limit
\begin{equation}
\underset{i \in I}{\lim} H^*(A_i)
\end{equation}
of of singular cohomology groups ?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that these maps induce a direct system on homology that you can take the colimit of.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you extend your argument please ? I'm not very familiar with these things.

Comment: Homotopic maps induce the same map on homology, therefore after passing to homology you just have an ordinary diagram indexed by $I$.  Take the limit of this diagram.